# Slow performance when dispatching a redux action from within setTimeout or Alert callback in RN

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

There is probably a good explanation for this but at the moment I'm very puzzled.

So the use case is that I want to dispatch a redux action either in a `setTimeout` block or in an `Alert.alert` callback in RN. What I'm noticing is that if the code runs this way then it's much slower.

For instance, the code is the below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addTag } from '../redux/actions';
import { Button, View, Alert } from 'react-native';

export const HomePerfTest = connect(
  null,
  dispatch => ({
    addTag: (tag, category) => dispatch(addTag(tag, category)),
  })
)(props => (
  <View>
    <Button
      title="Press me"
      onPress={() => {
        addRandomTags(props.addTag);
      }}
    />
    <Button
      title="Press me"
      onPress={() => {
        Alert.alert('Add random tags', null, [
          {
            text: 'Yes',
            onPress: () => {
              addRandomTags(props.addTag);
            },
          },
          {
            text: 'No',
          },
        ]);
      }}
    />
  </View>
));

const addRandomTags = addTag => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    measure(
      () =>
        addTag(
          {
            name: 'test' + i,
          },
          'test'
        ),
      'addTag'
    );
  }
};

const measure = (f, label) => {
  var t0 = new Date().getTime();
  const value = f();
  var t1 = new Date().getTime();
  console.log(label + ' took ' + (t1 - t0) + ' milliseconds.');
  return value;
};
```

Now when pressing the 1st button the `addTag` runs in 0-1 milliseconds. When pressing the second button (and then clicking Yes) it takes 4-8 milliseconds and therefore several times slower.

This case is not that bad, but I've implemented something similar in another page in my app in which the difference is massive. It takes ~2 milliseconds to run normally and >100ms to execute if it runs from within an `Alert` callback.

For now I've done a workaround by using a different alert module as opposed to the RN Alert. However I noticed that the same behaviour exists if I just wrap the code in a `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(() => addRandomTags(props.addTag));
```

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** - I can see exactly the same delay when wrapping code in `requestAnimationFrame` as well.

Comment: Do you clear the timeout when you're finished with it? I had an issue previously where the timeout will keep running even on separate tabs because of how the app is structured, and had to add lifecycle hooks to clear it properly.

Comment: No I'm not clearing the timeout, but tbh I don't see the problem you describe. Additionally I'm unsure if this could explain the performance degradation described even if it was.